# 2006 Honda Accord RPM is high

Tags: honda, accord

I have a Honda Accord v4 from 2006. Recently, I have noticed that my car is around 2500 rpm at 55 miles per hour. My mpg is heavily affected by this as I get 20-25 in combined driving. I was watching some YouTube videos and found that this Accord is normally around 1500 rpm at 60 miles an hour. So my 3 questions are one, is it true that my car should be around 1500 rpm at 60mph(not sure if the video was right) or is there some sort of problem and if so what is it, or is there nothing to worry about?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 20 to 25 MPG is amazing. 2500 RPM is due to the gear not shifting. It's not a rough idle situation, what happens if you let go of the accelerator pedal at 60 MPH speed? Does the RPM needle drop?

Comment: manual or automatic?

Comment: If its an automatic it sounds like it is not going into overdrive.

Comment: No it does not drop